# git sparse checkout unable to switch branches

Tags: git, git-checkout, sparse-checkout

I have a two branches main and feature branch. In both the branches there are two folders f1 and f2. There is a file inside f1 folder called file1.txt.

```
main branch structure

-root
 - f1
  - file1.txt
 - f2

feature branch structure 

-root
 - f1
  - file1.txt
 - f2
```

I want to clone f1 folder and its content using sparse checkout and after that I want to switch branches. How can i do that?

What I have tried:

```
git clone <link to repo> --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --sparse
cd <folder name>
git sparse-checkout set f1/
git fetch --all
git branch -a
git checkout feature
```

doing this i get this error "error: pathspec 'feature' did not match any file(s) known to git"

can someone guide me here?

Answer (score 0):

First, use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), not the [obsolete `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) command.

`git switch` is made to *not* work with files, but only branches.
So there won't be any `pathspec 'feature' did not match any file(s) known to git` error message, since git switch will *not* be looking for files, but branches to switch to.

Second, if you do see `origin/feature` in `git branch -a` output, the [guess mode of `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) will automatically create the local branch linked to the remote tracking branch `origin/feature`, equivalent to:

```
git switch -c feature --track origin/feature
```